# MVC dynamic URL

Tags: .net, url, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

As I know the urls in MVC model is based on the controllers. But I'm facing this problem that I can't wrap my head around it :

- What if I'm designing a beverage website, and I have to use different URL for each brand. For example : `beverage.com/pepsi, beverage.com/cocacola, beverage.com/sprit, beverage.com/7up`. These URLs will all lead to a same page called productdescription, the only difference is the description (image, ingredients, price etc)
- So is there any efficent way for this task? I don't want to create new controlers for each product!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your common controller name is `ProductController` and Method name is `Description`.
Now in RouteConfig.cs you can add route as mentioned below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PepsiRoute",
    "Pepsi/{id}",
    new { controller = "Product", action = "Description", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
    "CockRoute",
    "Cock/{id}",
    new { controller = "Product", action = "Description", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

**Note:** Above routes should be placed before default route. Otherwise you will face run-time exception `The controller for path '{PATH}' could not be found.`

**Update:**

For multiple brands if you don't want to register route for specific brand then you can map route as mentioned below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AllBrand",
    "Product/{name}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "About", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Then your URL will be :

- {domain}/Product/Pepsi
- {domain}/Product/Pepsi/2
- {domain}/Product/Cock/14
- {domain}/Product/Cock

  etc...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just to clarify: so if there are more brands, I will have to add more map routes?

Comment: I can't test right now, but it seems like it's the solution I'm looking for. Thanks for the answer !

Comment: Freudian slip ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a Rest Controller. Here are the steps:

1-Declare your rest servlet en web.xml (Websphere example):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyRestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>mipackage.MyRestServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>requestProcessorAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyRestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

2-Implement the RestServlet

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class RestServlet extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(BeverageController.class);
        return classes;
    }

}
```

3-Implement your Rest Controller:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

@Path("/{beverage}")
@ApplicationScoped
public class BeverageController {
    {
        @GET
        public String getBeverage(@PathParam("beverage") String beverage){
            //fetch order
        }
    }  
}
```